# Why my htaccess is not working when i upload it to ionos webspace?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried in in my localhost at it worked fine but after I upload it to my ionos webspace the website index is working but after I click the content it is not directing to anywhere and there is an error message:

> Error 404 not foound, Your browser can't find the document corresponding to the URL you typed in.

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) news.php?url=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^seksikateg/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) seksikateg.php?kategori=$1 [NC,L]
```

and i placed he file in the same place as the `index.php`, `news.php`, and `seksikateg.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that MultiViews is enabled at your host and this will break your rules since this will append the `.php` extension before mod_rewrite processes the request.

However, your directives are also in the wrong order. The generic rewrite to append the `.php` extension should appear after the other rules.

Your rewrite to append the `.php` extension is not strictly correct as it could result in a rewrite loop (500 error) under certain circumstances.

Try it like this instead:

```
# Ensure that MutliViews is disabled
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ news.php?url=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^seksikateg/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ seksikateg.php?kategori=$1 [NC,L]

# Append ".php" extension on other URLs
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I've also added the end-of-string anchor to the regex of your existing rewrites, otherwise you are potentially matching too much. eg. `/news/foo/bar/baz` would have also been rewritten to `news.php?url=foo` - potentially creating duplicate content and opening up your site to abuse.

I would also question the use of the `NC` flag on these rewrites. If this is required then you potentially have a duplicate content issue.

No need to backslash-escape literal dots in a regex character class and the `NC` flag is certainly redundant on the last rule.

Comment: thank you sooo much for the explanation, i actually solved it by adding slash in front of the file name , i wrote RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /news.php?url=$1 [NC,L] instead of RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ news.php?url=$1 [NC,L],  but your explanation is great !!

Comment: @alvianramaditya Adding the slash alone should not have made a difference unless perhaps you have other directives (eg. `RewriteBase`) that you've not included in the question? (Did you also need to add the slash to the generic rule that adds the `.php` extension?)